# FFMPEG cut out group of frames

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, crop, trim

I'm looking for a command to cut out exact frames from a video.

I know that I can do this by slicing  the video in two and then concat, 
but I'm looking for a sigle command to achive the same result,
something like:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -cutframe 1239 video_cut.mov
```

or something like

```
ffmpeg -ss 2348 -i video.mov -tt 2349 video_cut.mov
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -vf select='not(eq(n\,1239))' -c:a copy video_cut.mov
```